# How to programmatically render a view pager?

Tags: views, 8, paging

I'm trying to figure out how to render a view's pager programmatically. I'm renderering my view programmatically as follows:

```
$viewname = 'example_view';
$viewdisplay = 'block';

// get the view machine id
$view = Views::getView($viewname);
// set the display machine id
$view->setDisplay($viewdisplay);
$view->render();

$renderer = $view->rowPlugin;
foreach ($view->result as $index => $row) {
  $view->row_index = $index;
  $vars['content']['view_results'][$index] = $renderer->render($row);
}
```

So now I need to render the pager, but not having any luck. I've tried something like:

```
$pagerrenderer = $view->pager;
$vars['content']['view_pager'] = $pagerrenderer->render($view->pager);
```

but then end up with the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to pager_query_add_page()
>   must be of the type array, object given, called in
>   /www/projectname/docroot/core/includes/pager.inc on line 246 and defined
>   in pager_query_add_page() (line 311 of core/includes/pager.inc).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add per the documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/function/PagerPluginBase::render/8.1.x you should pass extra GET information to the render method and not the pager itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned from `$views->pager()` is an object implementing [`ViewsPluginInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21ViewsPluginInterface.php/interface/ViewsPluginInterface/8.2.x) and extending [`PagerPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/class/PagerPluginBase/8.2.x). If you look at the parameters [`PagerPluginBase::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21PagerPluginBase.php/function/PagerPluginBase%3A%3Arender/8.2.x) accepts, you will see they are:

> **$input**: Any extra GET parameters that should be retained, such as exposed input.

If you look at [`Full::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21pager%21Full.php/function/Full%3A%3Arender/8.2.x), you have an idea of how that parameter is used.

```
  $tags = array(
    0 => $this->options['tags']['first'],
    1 => $this->options['tags']['previous'],
    3 => $this->options['tags']['next'],
    4 => $this->options['tags']['last'],
  );
  return array(
    '#theme' => $this->themeFunctions(),
    '#tags' => $tags,
    '#element' => $this->options['id'],
    '#parameters' => $input,
    '#quantity' => $this->options['quantity'],
    '#route_name' => !empty($this->view->live_preview) ? '<current>' : '<none>',
  );
```

In any case, you don't pass to the method of that object the object itself.

Comment: Ah, Thanks for this - it definitely helped me understand my problem. I managed to get my pager using `$input = array();
    $vars['content']['view_pager'] = $view->pager->render($input);`